# Do I add external users to a Sharepoint group or a M365 group, if I want them to have read access to a site (teams)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365-groups

I have a teams site for external users, with a library where they can download reports. They only need 'read' permissions on this site.

Do I add them to the Sharepoint (OOTB) visitors group? Or add them to the existing M365 site's security group, as visitors? Or do I create a separate security group for them in M365?

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to the SharePoint visitors group or create a group in site and grant the group read permission. What matters is not what group they are but the permission levels they have. Groups are just a way to make it easier to manage users, by putting users with the same permission levels in a group and giving them the same permissions.